# Bitbucket workflow

Tags: git, bitbucket, phpstorm, pull-request, branching-and-merging

I want to know the flow for git and bitbucket with branches.

Lets say I have the following branches created on Bitbucket:

Master
Feature1
Feature2

On phpstorm I cloned the repository and now I checked out branch Feature1

I did my changes and committed.

What should I do next?

Should I

1.checkout master

2. pull the changes for master
3. then merge it to Feature1 branch

before I push my Feature1 branch changes to the remote Feature1 and then create a pull request?

I tried looking on the bitbucket documentation but couldn't find this.

The concern I have is how can I sync with the master branch before I push my feature1 to the remote feature1 so that I can do a pull request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many workflow variants, but I'd suggest this typical process :

```
# update your local master
git checkout master
git pull

# integrate recent changes from master into your branch
git checkout Feature1
git rebase master

# at this point, if any, resolve all conflicts normally and proceed

# then you can send your branch to the remote
git push origin HEAD
```

...then finally, on Bitbucket, create a pull request `Feature1 > master`

Comment: Is there a way to do it without rebase?

Comment: @RipChol Absolutely. You could as well do `git merge master` instead, but many people prefer a more linear workflow. Overall, this is mostly a matter of preference, as both do the job.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to say. Switch to master, pull it, then rebase your branch on top of it. Now push your branch. You have thus ensured that your branch can be merged with minimal fuss thru a pull request, because you have made your branch look as if it branched from the most recent state of master.